# How do i add a security group as an inbound rule to another security group in terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, security-groups, amazon-eks, eks

I have a Terraform codebase which deploys a private EKS cluster, a bastion host and other AWS services. I have also added a few security groups to the in Terraform. One of the security groups allows inbound traffic from my Home IP to the bastion host so that i can SSH onto that node. This security group is called `bastionSG`, and that works fine also.

However, initially I am unable to run kubectl from my bastion host, which is the node I use to carry out my kubernetes development on against the EKS cluster nodes. The reason is because my EKS cluster is a private and only allows communication from nodes in the same VPC and i need to add a security group that allows the communication from my bastion host to the `cluster control plane` which is where my security group bastionSG comes in.

So my routine now is once Terraform deploys everything, I then find the automatic generated EKS security group and add my `bastionSG` as an inbound rule to it through the AWS Console (UI) as shown in the image below.

[image]

I would like to NOT have to do this through the UI, as i am already using Terraform to deploy my entire infrastructure.

I know i can query an existing security group like this

```
data "aws_security_group" "selectedSG" {
  id = var.security_group_id
}
```

In this case, lets say `selectedSG` is the security group creared by EKS once terraform is completed the apply process. I would like to then add an inbound rule of `bastionSG` to it without it ovewriting the others it's added automatically.

**UPDATE: > EKS NODE GROUP**

```
resource "aws_eks_node_group" "flmd_node_group" {
  cluster_name    = var.cluster_name
  node_group_name = var.node_group_name
  node_role_arn   = var.node_pool_role_arn
  subnet_ids      = [var.flmd_private_subnet_id]
  instance_types = ["t2.small"]

  scaling_config {
    desired_size = 3
    max_size     = 3
    min_size     = 3
  }

  update_config {
    max_unavailable = 1
  }

  remote_access {
    ec2_ssh_key = "MyPemFile"
    source_security_group_ids = [
      var.allow_tls_id,
      var.allow_http_id, 
      var.allow_ssh_id,
      var.bastionSG_id
     ]
  }

  tags = {
    "Name" = "flmd-eks-node"
  }
}
```

As shown above, the EKS node group has the bastionSG security group in it. which i expect to allow the connection from my bastion host to the EKS control plane.

**EKS Cluster**

```
resource "aws_eks_cluster" "flmd_cluster" {
  name     = var.cluster_name
  role_arn = var.role_arn

  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids =[var.flmd_private_subnet_id, var.flmd_public_subnet_id, var.flmd_public_subnet_2_id]
    endpoint_private_access = true
    endpoint_public_access = false
    security_group_ids = [ var.bastionSG_id]
  }
}
```

`bastionSG_id` is an output of the security group created below which is passed into the code above as a variable.

**BastionSG security group**

```
resource "aws_security_group" "bastionSG" {
  name        = "Home to bastion"
  description = "Allow SSH - Home to Bastion"
  vpc_id      = var.vpc_id

  ingress {
    description      = "Home to bastion"
    from_port        = 22
    to_port          = 22
    protocol         = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks      = [<MY HOME IP address>]
  }

  egress {
    from_port        = 0
    to_port          = 0
    protocol         = "-1"
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "Home to bastion"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend existing security groups with the Terraform AWS "aws_security_group_rule" which accepts an arbitrary but required security group ID. See:https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group_rule